# How is it that when I call a method 10000 times it throws out of memory error?

Tags: java, algorithm, memory-management, out-of-memory, java-memory-model

### Situation

I was tasked to implement a string anagram problem in a live coding interview. The problem was given two strings, code the logic for the method `boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2)`.

### Solution

I presented the following solution(the mergeSort is an implementation of my own, and the containsChar is using a binary search that is also my own implementation)

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String value, String valueToCompare) {
    String temp = valueToCompare.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
    String t = value.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
    if (t.length() == temp.length()) {
        char[] c = t.toCharArray();
        char[] orderedChars = MergeSort.mergeSort(temp.toCharArray());
        for (int i = 0; i < orderedChars.length ; i++) {
                if (!containsChar(orderedChars, c[i], 0, orderedChars.length - 1))
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The efficiency of the solution is redundant, i'm more concerned on what is happening in the background.

### Question

Once I presented the solution the interviewer asked me, 
Lets suppose I have a computer with significantly low memory, and I want to run this
algorithm 10.000 times with random strings of size between 1000 and 10000, what would happened to your code?. I didn't know what to answer, so he told me that I would get a OutOfMemoryError exception. I know(or I least think) that because of the efficiency of the algorithm I would get such exception.
So my question is:

1. Why is throwing an OutOfMemoryError exception?
2. If I call that method 1000 times, is it because it takes to long to complete one call that such exception is thrown?
3. What is happening in the background when I call that method x amount of times?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207468/discussion-on-question-by-sandino-sanchez-how-is-it-that-when-i-call-a-method-10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let be clear on this.

- The Interviewer has asked you a *hypothetical* question
- The Interviewer did not specify the conditions properly (more later)
- The Interviewer has asserted that something *will* happen ... with no proof, and no way to validate that assertion.

> Lets suppose I have a computer with significantly low memory ... so he told me that I would get a `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

I think the Interviewer was probably wrong.

First of all, your code has no obvious memory leaks.  Not that I can see, and not that other commenters can see.

Your solution code does generate a few temporary objects on each call.  I can count up to 6 temporary strings and 1 or 2 temporary arrays, plus potentially other temporary objects created by some library methods.  You could probably reduce that ... *if it was worth the expending developer time on the optimization*.

But temporary objects by themselves should not lead to an OOME.  Modern Oracle / OpenJDK garbage collectors are really good at collecting short term objects.

Except in a couple of pathological scenarios:

### Scenario #1.

Suppose that you were *already* on the cusp of running out of memory.  For instance, suppose that before you started the 1000 method calls, you only had a small amount of free (eden) space *after running a full GC*.

For your task to complete, it will generate in the order of 1000 times x 10 objects x 10,000 bytes of temporary space.  That is about 100MB.

- If you have 10MB of Eden space free that means that you will need to do roughly 10 Eden space collections in a short period of time.
- If you have 1MB of Eden space free that means that you will need to do roughly 100 Eden space collections in a short period of time.

10 Eden space collections back to back *could be sufficient* to cause an OOME "Overhead limit exceeded".  With 100, it is much more likely.

But the bottom line is that if you are running close enough to a full heap, *any* piece of code that allocates an object could be the final straw.  The real problem is that your heap is too small for the task ... or *something else* is creating / retaining too many *long term* objects.

### Scenario #2.

Suppose that your application has stringent latency requirements.  To implement this you configure the JVM to use a low-pause collector, and you set some really aggressive latency goals for the collector.   And you don't have a lot of memory as well.

Now if your application generates too much garbage too fast, a low-pause collector may not be able to keep up.  If you push it beyond the limit, the GC will fall back to doing a stop-the-world collection to try to recover.  You *might* get an OOME ... though I doubt it.  But you will certainly fail to meet your latency goals.

But the bottom line if you have an application with requirements like this, it is essential that you run it on a machine with sufficient resources; i.e. enough spare memory, an enough cores that a (parallel) GC can keep up.  You would possibly design your `isAnagram` method to be (erm) a bit more *careful* in the way it creates temporary objects ... but you would know up front that you needed to do that.

### Recap

Returning to question posed by your Interviewer (as relayed by you):

- The Interviewer doesn't say how much free heap space there is, so we can't say if Scenario #1 would apply.  But if it did, the real problem would be either a mismatch between the heap size and the problem, or a memory leak *somewhere else* in the application.
- The Interviewer doesn't mention latency constraints.  Even if they existed, the first step would be to spec the hardware and use appropriate (i.e. realistic) JVM GC settings.
- If you did run into problems (OOMEs, missed latency goals), *then* you start looking for solutions.  Use memory profiling to identify the *nature* of the problem (e.g. is it caused by temp objects, long term objects, a memory leak, etc) and to track down the source of the problematic objects.

  Don't just assume a particular bit of code *will* cause OOMEs ... as the Interviewer is doing.   Premature optimization is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Make It Work. Make It Right. Make It Fast.

It's way too early to think about performance or memory usage. Your method returns false positive since it only checks if every letter in the first word is included in the second word.

With this check, `'aaa'` and `'abc'` are considered to be anagrams, but not `'abc'` and `'aaa'`.

Here's a complete class to test your code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class AnagramTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] anagrams = {
                { "abc", "cba" },
                { "ABC", "CAB" },
                { "Clint Eastwood", "Old West action" }
        };

        for (String[] words : anagrams) {
            if (isAnagram(words[0], words[1])) {
                System.out.println(".");
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                        "OH NO! '" + words[0] + "' and '" + words[1] + "' are anagrams but isAnagram returned false.");
            }
        }

        String[][] notAnagrams = {
                { "hello", "world" },
                { "aabb", "aab" },
                { "abc", "aaa" },
                { "aaa", "abc" },
                { "aab", "bba" },
                { "aab", "bba" },
        };

        for (String[] words : notAnagrams) {
            if (isAnagram(words[0], words[1])) {
                System.out.println(
                        "OH NO! '" + words[0] + "' and '" + words[1] + "' are not anagrams but isAnagram returned true.");
            } else {
                System.out.println(".");
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isAnagram(String value, String valueToCompare) {
        String temp = valueToCompare.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
        String t = value.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
        if (t.length() == temp.length()) {
            char[] c = t.toCharArray();
            char[] orderedChars = mergeSort(temp.toCharArray());
            for (int i = 0; i < orderedChars.length; i++) {
                if (!containsChar(orderedChars, c[i], 0, orderedChars.length - 1))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Dummy method. Warning: sorts chars in place.
    private static char[] mergeSort(char[] chars) {
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        return chars;
    }

    // replace with your binary search if you want.
    private static boolean containsChar(char[] orderedChars, char c, int m, int n) {
        for (int i = m; i <= n; i++) {
            if (orderedChars[i] == c) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
OH NO! 'aaa' and 'abc' are not anagrams but isAnagram returned true.
OH NO! 'aab' and 'bba' are not anagrams but isAnagram returned true.
OH NO! 'aab' and 'bba' are not anagrams but isAnagram returned true.
```

Here's an example implementation which should pass all the tests:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String word1, String word2) {
    word1 = word1.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
    word2 = word2.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
    return Arrays.equals(mergeSort(word1.toCharArray()), mergeSort(word2.toCharArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess:

- You have a problem in your MergeSort, which you haven't shown us;
- It doesn't happen on every input, so the interviewer wants you to run it 10000 times with random inputs to make it happen with high probability;
- The problem can cause your merge sort to recurse much too deeply.  Maybe O(N) instead of O(log N) depth, or maybe an infinite recursion; and
- Your merge sort unnecessarily allocates a new temporary array in every recursive call.  Since there are way too many of them, this results in an out of memory error.

Comment: Yeah i think he want to push me to find a better solution without sorting at all.